# How can I Detect when a Firefox WebPanel is closed?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am interested in opening a webPanel on the right side of the Firefox window.  Based on [an MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Sidebar), I determined that this could be done by setting the browser element's `direction` style.  However, I wish to clear out this setting after the webPanel is closed.  Is there a way I can detect this? Thus far, the only way I can think of is to poll `sidebarWindow.location.href` (to detect if the sidebar is changed) and `sidebarHidden` (to detect if the sidebar is closed).

```
var browser = document.getElementById('browser');
browser.style.direction = "rtl";

var sidebarWindow = document.getElementById("sidebar").contentWindow;
var sidebarBox = document.getElementById('sidebar-box');
var sidebarHidden = sidebarBox.collapsed || sidebarBox.hidden;

sidebarWindow.addEventListener("unload", function (event) {
    alert("1"); //This code fires when the web panel is opened
                //but not when it is closed.
});
sidebarBox.addEventListener("unload", function (event) {
    alert("2"); //This code does not fire.
});
sidebarWindow.addEventListener("close", function (event) {
    alert("3"); //This code does not fire.
});
sidebarBox.addEventListener("close", function (event) {
    alert("4"); //This code does not fire.
});  

openWebPanel('Test', 'http://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC there are essentially three ways a sidebar can be "closed":

1. The user closes it using the GUI (X-box) or keyboard shortcut. In this case, the web panel will not necessarily get unloaded, so there is no `unload` event.
2. Another document is loaded into the web panel. In this case you *might* get an `unload`.
3. The user opens another panel. There is not necessarily an `unload`.

Should you go forward with your implementation, you need to make sure your code handles all three correctly.

1. and 3. should be observable by the [`<broadcaster id="viewWebPanelsSidebar">`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser-sets.inc#141) changing the `checked` attribute (see the implementation of [`toggleSidebar()`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.js#4718)), so you could have another element observing and acting on [`onbroadcast`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Broadcasters_and_Observers#Broadcast_event).
2. should listen for `unload` and act accordingly.

To get proper `unload` events, I think the following should do the trick:

```
sidebar.contentDocument.getElementById("web-panels-browser")).
  addEventListener("unload", ...);
```

But my memory there is a bit wonky, so you might need to fiddle with that a bit. (The sizebar has a `<xul:browser id="web-panels-browser">` which displays the actual content...)

After having said all that: **I think it is a bad idea to mess with the sidebar like this.**
The MDN wiki(!) has bad advice in this case.

- The sidebar was not designed to be messed with like this.
- There are other add-ons "competing" with yours when it comes to messing with the sidebar.
- The sidebar code is, for the most part, pretty archaic and under-maintained. Getting things like your requirement to work correctly is pretty hard. There still might be other code (in add-ons) that could dismiss the sidebar that you and I didn't think of.
- The sidebar might not be the best place to display your content in the first place (what that content would be you didn't say). If it's something like context-help, dictionary/definition lookup results, login forms, then it won't be a good fit.
- Some users might not like that their always-on bookmarks/history sidebar gets replaced by yours. You could handle this by re-opening the previous one, but that will only complicate matters further.

You might be better off using some other way to display information - e.g. a new tab, a panel, a new sidebar like the social sidebar... E.g the social sidebar is not only on the right, it actually is a standalone sidebar not part of the "main" sidebar.